# stack.sty and \end{environment}

Tags: environments, programming, enumerate, itemize, stack

I'm writing a multilevel `itemize` list environment to simplify the process of putting nested lists in Beamer slides, and I want it to support `enumerate` lists as well. The `mitemize` environment is supposed to work as follows:

```
\begin{mitemize}
  \enumeratelist
  \mitem{1} Candidate Generation
  \mitem{2} From annotated data
  \mitem{2} Using heuristics from unannotated data
  \mitem{1} Connect the slots to create trees
  \mitem{1} Pruning and Sorting
  \mitem{2} Covering algorithm on annotated corpus
  \mitem{2} Sorting linkage specifications by structure
\end{mitemize}
```

Which is supposed to look as follows:

[image]

I've gotten the package working with one problem: whenever `mitemize.sty` tries to close an `enumerate` or `itemize` list, the result is an error message:

```
\begin{itemize} on input line 104 ended by \end{itemize}.
```

or

```
\begin{enumerate} on input line 504 ended by \end{enumerate}.
```

Apparently `\Push{stackname}{itemize}\end{\Stack{stackname}}`
isn't the same as `\end{itemize}`. Any ideas how to fix this:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mitemize}
\RequirePackage{stack}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\NewStack{mitemizeStack}{\empty}
\newcounter{mitemize@depth}

\newenvironment{mitemize}{
   \newcommand{\mitem}[1]{%
      \whiledo{\value{mitemize@depth}>##1}{%
     \end{\Stack{mitemizeStack}}%
     \Pop{mitemizeStack}%
     \addtocounter{mitemize@depth}{-1}%
      }%
      \whiledo{\value{mitemize@depth}<##1}{%
     \addtocounter{mitemize@depth}{1}%
     \Push{mitemizeStack}{itemize}
     \begin{itemize}%
      }%
      \item%
   }%
   \newcommand{\enumeratelist}{%
     \addtocounter{mitemize@depth}{1}%
     \Push{mitemizeStack}{enumerate}
     \begin{enumerate}%
   }%
}{
   \whiledo{\value{mitemize@depth}>0}{%
      \end{\Stack{mitemizeStack}}%
      \Pop{mitemizeStack}%
      \addtocounter{mitemize@depth}{-1}%
   }%
}
```

---

Here's a more minimal example to play with. The output is correct, but I get the error `\begin{itemize} on input line 7 ended by \end{itemize}.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stack}
\NewStack{endenvstack}{\empty}
\begin{document}

\Push{endenvstack}{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo
\item Bar
\item Baz
\end{\Stack{endenvstack}}

Text that comes after the list

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a working version by putting creating new commands to hide the `\end{enumerate}` and `\end{itemize}` and calling them using csname.

In my minimal example, this works out to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stack}

\newcommand{\wrapenditemize}{\end{itemize}}    %create a wrapper

\NewStack{endenvstack}{\empty}
\begin{document}

\Push{endenvstack}{wrapenditemize}             %the wrapper's name is pushed as normal text
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo
\item Bar
\item Baz
\csname\Stack{endenvstack}\endcsname           %the wrapper's name is popped as normal text
                                               %and then turned into a macro call
                                               %using \csname

Text that comes after the list

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is the way LaTeX defines `\@checkend` as `\def\@checkend#1{\def\reserved@a{#1}\ifx\reserved@a\@currenvir \else\@badend{#1}\fi}`. The use of `ifx` means that the unexpanded contents of `\reserved@a` (in this case `\Stack{endenvstack}`) are checked for to see whether they match the environment name, and if they don't, an error message is printed. The rest of the `\end` macro works the way it should in the presence of commands that evaluate to the environment name.